# Passing a tf.data.Dataset that returns dicts to Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

## Background

As far as I can tell, Keras will become the preferred way of writing eager/lazy agnostic models [(source)](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#build_a_model). There also seems to be support for `tf.data` with Keras ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets)) which is great because that's the ETL I'm using for my current `tf.estimator` project.

## Problem

I'd like to keep my `tf.data` pipeline but replace my `tf.estimator` with a `tf.keras.Model`, however after porting my graph I get tripped up by a

```
ValueError: Please do not pass a dictionary as model inputs.
```

upon calling `model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=n)` which seems weird to me because `tf.data`/`tf.estimator` was built to work with `(features: dict, labels: dict)` where values in the dicts are tensors.

## Summary

How can I use `tf.keras.Model` with dicts?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9805) similar to you case ?

Answer (score 2):

A temporary workaround is to work with tuples of tensors instead of dicts, for example by calling

```
def flatten(dataset):
    return dataset.map(lambda features, labels: (tuple(features.values()), tuple(labels.values())))
```

before `model.fit`, while making sure `Model.call` goes by indices instead of keys (e.g. `return tuple(outputs.values())` etc.).

**Unfortunately:**
The above hack only works with training data. For `model.fit(validation_data=flatten(validation_dataset), ...)` it won't work due to some internal bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21729